# Protecting BJTs from overvoltage

Tags: transistors, bjt, over-voltage-protection

I'm building an electronic load and I need to protect the transistors from overvoltage. This is the over-simplified version of it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQVuEv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I can't use a relay, because what if voltage changes after the relay is connected? Aside from that, I couldn't find a relay with contact voltage rating higher than 30 VDC.

I can't use any transistors because it's a 200W load with maximum current of 10A, any transistor there would be fried without a proper heatsink that I don't have. (I only have a big heatsink with fan for the main transistors.)

Can varistors help or are they too slow? How do I protect the transistors from over voltage?

Electronic load spec: 50 V / 10 A / 200W

[2N3055 datasheet.](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3055-D.PDF)

Comment: Varistors are for shunting transient voltage spikes, not sustained current shunting. Really you protect the transistors from over-voltage by not applying over-voltage. What is the purpose of this circuit? Are you testing power supplies or what?

Comment: @Transistor Yeah, it's just a "dummy load" for testing PSUs and batteries etc. So there's no way to protect the input from possible errors?

Comment: What would happen if the power supply feeding the switch (called Input Voltage) were shorted out by a crowbar circuit? Would the power supply survive i.e. is the supply self-protecting even if it can generate more than 50 volts?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't care what happens to the input source, I just want to protect the BJTs. what's a crowbar circuit?

Comment: But, what would happen like how much current could the input voltage deliver if it were shorted out?

Comment: @Andyaka We can add a 10A fuse, I just googled crowbar circuit but I'm not familiar with thyristors, have to learn more about them...

Comment: That's what I'd consider using and a fuse - choose one that uses the TL431 and, of course, do a simulation!

Comment: @Andyaka You're the best, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](https://axotron.se/index_en.php?page=26#:%7E:text=Precision%20crowbar%20circuit&text=A%20low%2Dcost%20adjustable%20shunt,of%20the%20TL431%20is%20used.) a half decent-looking site for an explanation of an over-voltage crowbar protector. It has various circuits but ends up talking about the [MC3423 crowbar protection IC](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC3423-D.PDF): -

[image]

And, although I've never used this part, it appears to tick all the boxes. Alternatively use a TL431 device (commonly available) like this circuit shown in the link at the top: -

[image]

I think this might have components chosen for 5 volt over-protection so some value adjustments will need to be made for a voltage above + 40 volts. Simulation is going to be your best buddy here.

That site then moves on to describe a version that has improved di/dt protection for the triac/SCR/thyristor used. The site also gives some other links to useful pages.

Bottom line is that you will need to have a fuse in series with the 50 volt supply and the crowbar circuit works by detecting an over-voltage and shorting out the supply in microseconds hence, it relies on the fuse blowing.

Comment: Last question; Can I use an op amp to trigger the thyristor/triac?

Comment: *Can I use an op amp to trigger the thyristor/triac?* 1) You shouldn't be using an opamp but a **comparator**. 2) **Why** would you want to use an opamp/comparator when this circuit does the trick? 3) Don't ask: "Can I..." because when in a "silly" mood I could answer: "I can but I don't know if you can." or "Not if you don't have an opamp." A better question would be: *"I would like to use an opamp to trigger the thyristor, are there any (dis)advantages in doing that?"* Focus on **why** instead of "can I".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I want to use a comparator because TL431 can only set the voltage up to 36V, I have the supply in the circuit that is independent of the input voltage to supply the comparator, any advice on that? also should I use triac or thyristor? thanks.

Comment: You can implement a potential divider that protects the TL431 at higher voltages or use a zener diode to act as a shunt as shown in the link earlier on.

Comment: *should I use triac or thyristor?* Look up the difference between an TRIAC and a Thyristor. Then search for circuits: "TRIAC circuit" and "Thyristor circuit" and pay attention to what these devices are used for. Hint: it has to do with AC and DC. Stop "blindly" asking "should I use ..." and "can I use ..." without doing **ANY** prior research. We're not here to explain you the basics that can be found easily if you just look for them. If you show you've done your (re)search you'll get **much better answers**.